# Standard deviation function in oracle for DateTime format

Tags: c#, excel, oracle

How to use standard deviation for Time format. 
I have column with DateTime data and I want use standard deviation function 
but I don't have same result like when I use this data in excel.

Comment: What result do you get in each? It is possible that one is the population s.d. and the other is the sample s.d.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Oracle didn't implement average and standard deviation for dates (which is strange - they make perfect sense). Instead, you need to subtract a fixed date (SYSDATE is a perfect candidate); for standard deviation you don't need to add anything back, since subtracting a constant from all members of a sample does not change the standard deviation. If you wanted to compute the average, you would add SYSDATE back to the result. The standard deviation is in days; multiply by 24 if you need it in hours, or 86400 if you need it in seconds, etc.

Example:

```
with input_dates (dt) as (
        select to_date ('2016/03/20 13:30:31', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
        select to_date ('2016/03/22 03:14:32', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
        select to_date ('2016/03/30 09:12:43', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
        select to_date ('2016/04/02 19:22:35', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual 
     )
select stddev(0+to_number(sysdate - dt)) as sample_sd, 
       stddev_pop(dt - sysdate)          as population_sd
from   input_dates;
```

Output:

```
 SAMPLE_SD POPULATION_SD
---------- -------------
6.39233719    5.53592639
```

In Excel:

```
         3/20/2016 13:30
          3/22/2016 3:14
          3/30/2016 9:12
          4/2/2016 19:22
STDEVA       6.392417475
STDEV.P      5.535995925
```

The results are indeed slightly different; this is probably due to rounding, both in translating dates to numbers and in taking square roots and such.

Comment: Yes. I try that but excel give me result like 00:00:30 . In oracle i have doubel number format for this. I need 00:00:30 becose i represent that value on a chart in the pdf report. When I multiple value * 60 i give some adre result then 30 sec .

Comment: I don't understand. I included the result from Excel in my Answer, the standard deviation is exactly in the same format as in Oracle. Perhaps someone formatted the results of std. dev. for you in Excel to look that way?